# Calling c function, order of "import fmt", "import C" is causing build error, why?

Tags: go, cgo

## I have the following simple test go code :  call_c.go

```
package main

/*
int getData(int *p, int n )
{
     int i; 
     for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        p[i]=i;
    } 
    return n;
}
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a [5]int32
    i := C.getData((*C.int)(&a[0]), 5)
    fmt.Println(i, a)
}
```

I use "**go build call_c.go**" to build the program and that builds fine.

But I found that if I simplely reverse the order of "import fmt", "import C" or add a newline between the C /* */ block code and the first import statement, the "go build call_c.go" command will return an error:

```
go build call_c.go
37: error: 'getData' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

## Questions for expert gophers out there:

Why is the order of import important in go?

Why can't I add space between C block and the first import statement?

If I see this kind of error again, how best to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of import arn't generally important. But `import "C"` is very special when using cgo.

From the [docs](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/):

> If the import of "C" is immediately preceded by a comment, that
>   comment, called the preamble, is used as a header when compiling the C
>   parts of the package. For example:

```
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <errno.h>
import "C"
```

So, if you have a newline between your comment which contain the C code, and the `import "C"` , then the comment is just another comment, and isn't processed by cgo.

Similarly if you reverse the order of import:

```
/*
int getData(int *p, int n )
{
     int i; 
     for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        p[i]=i;
    } 
    return n;
}
*/
import "fmt"
import "C"
```

The code in the comment is just another comment and isn't processed by cgo since it isn't immediately followed by an import "C". (or rather, `import "C"` isn't preceded by a comment)

Comment: Good answer!  This is the first time I enter a language where a new line can cause a compilation error.   Now I know why.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's important only because that's the way the tool is defined to work -- [golang.org/cmd/cgo/](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

A lot of the Go tool-chain is convention based, and you need to follow the proper conventions for it to work properly.